# How to attach screen shot to XCUITest report in Jenkins. Can only see screenshot if running through XCODE

Tags: xctest

How to attach screen shot to XCUITest report in Jenkins. Can only see screenshot if running through XCODE

Steps

1. I have a job in Jenkins which builds and runs the XCUITest
2. But after completing there is no option to see the screenshot of failed   cases
3. I used xcpretty to generate HTML type report, but there also screenshot is not displayed. 
   it has a -screenshot attribute but that only accepts screenshot with a sepecified name. (like TestcaseName_Classname.jpg)
   But xcuitest takes screenshot with name 'screenshot_<>.jpg"

   Can anyone throw some information on this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot collection in xcpretty is broken as of now.

https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty/issues/251

You may use xcsummary as a workaround.

https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty/issues/251

Answer (score 0):

You need to point `attachment.name` as here

```
func takeScreenshot() {
        let screenshot = XCUIScreen.main.screenshot()
        let attachment = XCTAttachment(screenshot: screenshot)
        attachment.lifetime = .deleteOnSuccess
        attachment.name = UITest.sharedInstance.testCase.name
        add(attachment)
    }
```